# create JAVA Map out of JSON file using Jackson libraries

Tags: java, json, jackson, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am using CouchbaseLite to build embedded database of NoSQL type. Downloaded libraries for 1.3 version `couchbase-lite-java-1.3.1-community.zip` and added them to my Java project in eclipse.

Following are the tasks I want to achieve?

1. Read .json file (let us assume the file path `J:/temp/sample.json`)
2. Convert it to Map
3. Insert into CouchBase database.

Following is the code that I tried:

```
    CouchDBManager dbManager = new CouchDBManager();
    Database myDB = dbManager.createDataBase("atempt1");
    // first step
    File f = new File("J:/temp/sample.json");
    // code to read the content of a file
    // second step
    ObjectNode objectNode1 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    // add code to covert the json content read from the file to Map
    // third step
    Document doc = myDB.createDocument();
    doc.putProperties(map); // putProperties expectes Map object
```

So, kindly help me in reading the `json` file and convert it to `Map` using `Jackson` libraries so that I can create and insert the document into CouchbaseLite DB.

**Note:** `Jackson` libraries are part of `CouchBaseLite` that I downloaded, so I want a solution around it. I `don't want to use custom processing` of JSON file and convert it to Map, which is error prone and performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at Jackson data bind docs int the below link:

```
map = mapper.readValue(new File("J:/temp/sample.json"), HashMap.class);
```

returns a Map.

Reference:

1. http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.io.File,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType)